# Woocommerce custom orderby doesn't work in search results

Tags: php, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I've noticed that my custom sorting option works perfectly when browsing the shop but fails in search results. The current code follows many examples available:

```
// Add "Sort by discount" to sorting options. Defaults to biggest to smallest discount.

add_filter('woocommerce_get_catalog_ordering_args'
          ,'mycode_woocommerce_add_salediscount_to_catalog_ordering_args'
          );

function mycode_woocommerce_add_salediscount_to_catalog_ordering_args( $args ) {
    $orderby_value = isset( $_GET['orderby'] ) 
        ? wc_clean( $_GET['orderby'] ) 
        : apply_filters('woocommerce_default_catalog_orderby'
                       ,get_option('woocommerce_default_catalog_orderby' )
                       );
    if ( 'discount' == $orderby_value ) {
        $args['orderby']    = 'meta_value_num';
        $args['order']      = 'DESC';
        $args['meta_key']   = 'discount_amount';
    }
    return $args;
}

add_filter('woocommerce_default_catalog_orderby_options'
          ,'mycode_woocommerce_add_salediscount_to_catalog_orderby'
          );
add_filter('woocommerce_catalog_orderby'
          ,'mycode_woocommerce_add_salediscount_to_catalog_orderby'
          );

function mycode_woocommerce_add_salediscount_to_catalog_orderby( $sortby ) {
    $sortby['discount'] = __( 'Sort by discount', 'woocommerce' );
    return $sortby;
}
```

This code I've added to the `my_custom_code.php` which is a simple plugin for my own code.

It sorts based on a meta value that every product in my store has.

When used on a search results page, instead of the custom ordering, the ordering is the same as 'relevance'.

Looking through the WC code that controls ordering, I see that `is_search()` is called in multiple places, with ordering reset to 'relevance' but the default sorting options are able to override this and they still work (e.g. sort by price still works).

So I imagine that I need to adjust the code slightly to behave in the same way as the default search options but I can't see how to do this.

Does anyone know?

Thanks!

Comment: I've noticed more strange behaviour related to custom ordering.

I have the shortcode on my front page: `[products limit="4" columns="4" orderby="date" order="DESC" category="Locking carabiners"]`

If I set the default sorting option for my store (products) to my "Sort by discount", this over rides the above shortcode and the products displayed by the shortcode are no longer displayed by date but by discount amount!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I think I’ve got to the bottom of this. It’s not a problem with WC or wordpress. The code I’ve used is too simplistic and doesn’t account for all eventualities.

```
function mycode_woocommerce_add_salediscount_to_catalog_ordering_args( $args ) {
    $orderby_value = isset( $_GET['orderby'] ) 
        ? wc_clean( $_GET['orderby'] ) 
        : apply_filters('woocommerce_default_catalog_orderby'
                       ,get_option('woocommerce_default_catalog_orderby' )
                       );
    if ( 'discount' == $orderby_value ) {
        $args['orderby']    = 'meta_value_num';
        $args['order']      = 'DESC';
        $args['meta_key']   = 'discount_amount';
    }
    return $args;
}
```

The function first checks to see if the user has selected sorting by looking in the GET. If it’s not there then it retrieves the default sort order set in WC.

If either the GET or the default sort order are ‘discount’, then the discount sort order arguments are returned.

The problem is that this isn’t always the desired outcome. In search results, the desired sorting could be ‘relevance’ – indeed this is the one wordpress puts in the dropdown box. But the above code doesn’t care. If the default sort order is ‘discount’ then it sorts by that.

It seems to do the same for shortcode. For example the sorting could be “rand”, but the above code doesn’t check for that. It returns the discount arguments.